# Phonegap one time run proedure while installing app

Tags: cordova, installation, phonegap-plugins, uninstallation

I want to run procedure or block of javascript code only once at installation time and also at uninstalling.

For Example :--Add imei number entry in database via ajax while installing or removing that entry at uninstall time.

Those code is **suppose to run once after installation (First time launch the application)** and also run snippet of code while uninstalling the app

It's possible through phonegap if yes then please advise?
1)Is there any plugin for that?

Note:--> i'm pure javascript developer nothing to do with native code(Novice for native plateform)

Thanks for your time and consideration in advance.

-Niks

Comment: for knowing that it's the first time, you can use some localStorage variable. But sadly, there is no way of detecting uninstallings